# Jenkins build errors

Tags: linux, jenkins

I am trying to setup the build commands, I am getting these errors. 
I have tried setting up the security configuration.

Access control:

- Jenkins own user database.
- Allow users to sign up.

Authorization : Matrix based.

user group : joshis1 - checked all.

After running the build. I get the following errror.
In the build script, I am just trying to copy a file.

#### FailedConsole Output

```
Started by user shreyas joshi
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Tungsten-Build
[Tungsten-Build] $ /bin/sh /tmp/hudson1841543545003586844.sh
November26
November26
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got the answer for this one.

```
visudo
```

**Add following lines:**

```
<jenkins_user_id that u are using> ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

**Comment this line:**

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

Answer (score 3):

The visudo solution works, but instead of of commenting out

```
Defaults    requiretty
```

you could add the following line:

```
Defaults:<jenkins user> !requiretty
```

I should have added a comment, but my reputation is to low...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do this is by assigning TTY in /etc/passwd by changing e.g.

```
myuser:x:498:499::/var/www/:/sbin/nologin
```

to

```
myuser:x:498:499::/var/www/:/bin/bash
```